# Mixing audio stream and copy video

Tags: python, audio, video, heroku, ffmpeg

I need to implement two features:

1. replace the audio in the movie
2. mix the current audio with a new one

Solution for 1:

`ffmpeg -i music_url -i video_url -codec copy -y -shortest output_video`

Solution for 2:

`ffmpeg -i video_url -i music_url -filter_complex amix=duration=shortest -y output_video`

But there are a few problems with 2nd:

- Video is lower quality
- audio is cut the the shortest one, but video stays the same
- takes longer that copy streams

Any hints?

EDIT:

```
ffmpeg -i vid -i music -filter_complex amix=duration=shortest -shortest -y out_v
```

Seems it's not possible to stream copy video and filter audio. Need to figure out how to keep the video with the same quality, because the default behaviour lowers it.

Comment: "Mix the current audio with a new one". Mix is ambiguous. Assuming both inputs are stereo, do you want to 1) create one output audio stream consisting of 4 channels 2) create one output audio stream consisting of 2 channels (stereo), or 3) mux the additional stream resulting in two separate audio streams within the output?

Comment: Input video can upload by the user, so I have to assume all cases. My audio file will be stereo. The output should be stereo audio stream of both inputs muxed together (if mux means what I think in this context)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard in other words new audio should be a background music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to filter stream and copy it, but in this case I copy video and filter audio. Solution:

`ffmpeg -i v -i m -filter_complex amix=duration=shortest -vcodec copy -shortest -y out_v`